# How do I exclude a folder from a project but not from publish?

Tags: msbuild, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I've migrated an asp.net core project to VS2017 RC, which now supports the ability to exclude files from a project. I've excluded two folders, which added these lines to my csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="wwwroot\dist\**" />
  <Content Remove="wwwroot\lib\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This works great, except now those files don't get published anymore. How do I exclude these folders from the project but still include them on publish?

Comment: Begs the question, why do you want them excluded from the project if you want them published?

Comment: @DavidG so that they won't be picked up by visual studio find in files, show up in the solution explorer, etc. They are minified javascript/css files and external libraries.

Comment: Probably better to just hide them then. Does `DnxInvisibleFolder` still work? for example: `<ItemGroup><DnxInvisibleFolder Include="wwwroot\dist\" /></ItemGroup>`. Though I still don't understand why you care about not showing them in there.

Comment: No, that does not work. I care because Visual Studio find in files may take a long time and return hundreds of results for a search string from external libraries or minified files.

Comment: Are you able to right click on the folder in VS and hide it? That's how it worked previously.

Comment: Yes, which results in the lines in my question that are also removing it from publish.

Comment: In pre-csproj, there was a "hide" option that was distinct from "remove"

Answer (score 15):

The following msbuild items taken from the dotnet new spa templates helped me to achieve what I believe you are after:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\dist\**" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\lib\**" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="GiveAName" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="npm etc etc do your stuff" />
    <Exec Command="or webpack" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <DistFiles Include="wwwroot\dist\**; wwwroot\lib\**" />
        <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles-&gt;'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
            <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: I just tested this on VS2017 (v15.3.5) and it works. Thanks! As a side note, I removed the npm stuff, as I didn't need it.

Comment: no worries. FYI I also removed the npm commands also and found it far more efficient to handle the front end tasks outside of VS.

Comment: I am trying to get this to work but for a npm build directory outside of my .net project (backend is in one folder and during deploy, bundles UI resources from a second folder). Ie my dist files look like 
    <DistFiles Include="..\..\src-app\www\dist\**;" /> 
But I am struggling to get any output collected... i dont understand the syntax of the inlcude distfiles -> fullpath ?? has anyone else attempted this folder structure?

Answer (score 3):

I worked around this by adding the following lines to the `PrepublishScript` target in the csproj file, since there doesn't seem to be an elegant way to do it yet.

```
<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish" Condition=" '$(IsCrossTargetingBuild)' != 'true' ">
  <!-- Other things here already -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Lib Include="wwwroot/lib/**;" />
    <Dist Include="wwwroot/dist/**;" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(Lib)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\wwwroot\lib\%(RecursiveDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(Dist)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\wwwroot\dist\%(RecursiveDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

Comment: The code sample seems to expect a `PrepublishScript` target in the csproj. The ASP.NET Core web app template doesn't have this. In such a case, do you just add it inside the `Project` element?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to satisfy your needs with a `Condition` such as:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
  <Content Remove="wwwroot\dist\**" />
  <Content Remove="wwwroot\lib\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

EDIT:

Or perhaps try:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" Remove="wwwroot\dist\**" />
  <Content Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" Remove="wwwroot\lib\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

EDIT 2:

Since it looks like the IDE is going to respect the `Condition`, you could instead change items from `Content` to `None` and add a `BeforePublish` target that adds equivalent `Content` items.

EDIT 3:

So to be specific, keep your original

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="wwwroot\dist\**" />
  <Content Remove="wwwroot\lib\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and add, just before `</Project>`

```
<Target Name="BeforePublish">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="wwwroot\dist\**" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\lib\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 Solution Explorer ignores the `Condition`? I guess I should not be surprised. I added a variation just in case it coaxes the desired behavior from the IDE, but I doubt it will. :(

Comment: tried it, and publishing in visual studio fails to copy wwwroot at all, and using dotnet publish still excludes dist and lib even with the BeforePublish target

Comment: Can you provide the other <Content Include line(s) that are in the project file?

Comment: there are no other content include or remove lines

Comment: Try changing the target name from BeforePublish to BeforeBuild.